# Play Framework 2.3.x: Force Run on errors

Tags: playframework-2.3

Is it possible to force your play app to run in the browser, even though it has errors? This is so that I can more easily see the errors in the browser instead of searching through them in the console.

I am refactoring something which has over 300 errors, and thought it might be easier to see them one at a time in the browser.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean force run? You can't run an application with compile errors. But by default, Play will show compile errors one at a time in dev mode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no possible way of achieving what you desire. You can't run an application with compilation errors. It's like driving a car without wheels. The console and your IDE are your friends.